# Java - Selenium - Utilizar contains com list de elementos

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, lista

Tenho num site os produtos que foram adicionados no carrinho.
Quero verificar que o produto "Camiseta Teste" foi adicionado com sucesso.
Para isso, tenho uma string aonde esse valor (Camiseta Teste) está definido. Ex:
`String _product1 = "Camiseta Teste"`.

Porém, os produtos adicionados no carrinho tem o mesmo id (name). Nesse ID, quando utilizo um `gettext();` o nome de cada produto é retornado.

Eu quero fazer o seguinte:

Verificar se a string `_product1` é igual ao texto de algum desses produtos de id name.

Então meu código precisa pegar essa list de elementos (name). Checar o primeiro produto do carrinho, ver o que ele contém, se é igual à variável _product1, caso for, passar o teste. Caso não for, continuar até o último elemento existente da lista. Se algum desses elementos for igual à _product1, ok. Senão, o teste falha.

Comment: Não entendi direito, mas acho que da pra voce fazer algo como: `for(Objeto o : lista)`

Comment: Depois verifica: `if(o.getVariavel().contains("abc"){//faz algo}`

Comment: @Techies reformulei a pergunta novamente, se puder ainda me ajudar. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Tem como colocar a parte do HTML que contém os produtos? Acho que a melhor abordagem neste teu caso não é usar `id` do elemento, mas sim retornar todos os elementros filhos, seja usando uma classe CSS no elemento pai, `xpath`, etc.

Comment: Mais fácil

https://www.netshoes.com.br/account/wish-list.jsp

Se você escolher qualquer produto e adicionar na lista do carrinho, vc pode encontrá-lo pela cssSelector '.name' e pegar o texto da descrição dele. Só que esse css é igual para todos os produtos adicionados. Preciso checar um por um e verificar se o texto de algum deles bate com o da string inicial @BrunoCésar

Comment: Acho que o trecho de código que postei resolve seu problema.

Comment: @LuísGustavoVieira Isso é só na lista de desejos? Por que no carrinho normal é uma tabela com classe `table-products`, então é bem simples de fazer. Se for só na lista de desejo não consigo testar, não vou criar cadastro só pra isso, então se puder incluir a estrutura fica mais simples.